# Spnego Kerberos soap ui client error

Tags: web-services, kerberos, spnego

I am trying to use soap-ui 5.0.0. to make a call to web service using spnego-kerberos authentication.
I have followed:
http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/spnego-kerberos-authentication.html

My login.conf:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.login {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  client=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  debug=true
  useTicketCache=true
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="C:\\kerberos\\testuser.keytab"
  principal=testuser@XX1.AD.XX.COM
  doNotPrompt=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.accept {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required 
  client=true 
  useTicketCache=true;
};
```

However, when I make the call I get the following error:

```
ERROR:java.lang.SecurityException: Configuration Error:
    Line 11: expected [option key], found [null]
```

This seems to point to line 11 in login.conf:

```
keyTab="C:\\kerberos\\testuser.keytab"
```

ISSUE:
This is caused by line principal=testuser@XX1.AD.XX.COM.
It does not like the @XX1.AD.XX.COM, with principal=testuser, it proceeds further and but now I get authentication 401 error instead.

Please advise.
Thanks,
B.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the principal value with double quotes as for the keyTab.

> principal="testuser@XX1.AD.XX.COM"

And it will work as desired.

Cheers,
Piotr